# Formula returning "0"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with the following formula in cell F2

```
=IF($F2=0,IF($H2="Peer Review",TODAY(),VALUE($G2)),IF(AND($H2<>"Peer Review",$H2="Complete"),VALUE($F2),0))
```

[image]

But still, the formula is evaluating to "0".

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think that is a recursive error, because the cell is referring to itself in its formula.

Comment: how to solve that @cmdLP

Comment: Maybe you meant another cell with ``$F2`` in the formula. It does not make sence to use the ``$F2`` in the cell.

Comment: Agreed with @cmdLP. I just tried placing the following formula in cell `A1`: `=IF(A1=1,2,3)` and it returned a result of `0`. Apparently Excel always returns `0` in a cell that references itself, even if the formula would otherwise never return `0` in another cell. I find this interesting that it actually returns `0` rather than just returning an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go into your `Options` in excel and go to the `Formulas` tab in the `Calculation options` make sure that `Enable iterative calculations` is checked and `Maximum Iterations:` equals 1.  Then it should work.